# Wired Network Does not Connect on first Boot

Tags: networking

I am having a problem with one of my desktop computers not connecting to the wired network when I first turn it on in the morning.  After a restart, the wired network works fine. Any suggestions I could try to get this working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be of any help. Just a thought...

Do you switch on your Internet connection just before switching on your computer? Sometimes, it can take a cable/broadband modem/router as much as two-three minutes to start completely. If this is the case, then switch on your Internet connection and wait for some time before starting your computer.